# Adding a new line after a fold

Tags: folding

At the end of a file I have these lines, line 19 is actually a beginning of a 4 line fold.

Now if I want to add a new line after the fold, i.e a new line number 24, I usually type 'A' and enter which takes me to the beginning of a new line. But this fails when I have a fold. What happens is vim opens the fold and I get directed to the end of the first line.

What should be done to begin a new line without opening the fold

Also is there any better way to open a few line at the end of the document, what I do is I type 'A' that takes me to the end of the line and then press 'Enter'.

Thank you for your time.

```
18 Palatable:
19 +--  4 lines: adj 1: acceptable to the taste------------------------
~
~
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `o` command to add a new line below the current one. That will work with folds, and insert a line below the fold.

See [`:help o`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#o) for more details on this command.

Comment: VSCode Vim user here. When I "o", the cursor opens the fold and inserts new  line on the first inner-most line of the fold. Any idea how I could fix this?